# Нужна ли запятая перед "как у..."?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, сравнительный-оборот, оборот-с-как

*Хотя брови у него(,) как у Брежнева.*

Чисто интуитивно читается без неё, но правило запятой при сравнении вносит смуту. Тяжко отличать сравнительный оборот от обстоятельства образа действия...

Comment: Что за "о. д."?

Comment: Обстоятельство образа действия...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кратко ответить не получится. А для начала хотел бы обратиться к тем, кто постоянно хочет закрыть вопрос, подобный этому.  У нас что – на сайте места не хватает? Или вам настолько скучно от "одинаковых" вопросов? Так пройдите мимо. Дайте возможность спрашивающему разобраться! Именно разобраться! А отвечающему, относительно недавно, а может и давно, углубившемуся в определенную тему, – еще немного поточить эту тему или даже окончательно выработать для себя, если хотите, алгоритм. Вéрхом такого образования, как мне кажется, будет чистое озарение.     Данный вопрос-то ведь – не домашнее задание. И автор, оперируя термином в сокращенном виде (что на самом деле может ввести в ступор, и это уже исправили), не просто хочет получить ответ "да" или "нет".

По существу. Здесь снова вступают в силу интуиция (что отмечено в вопросе), интонация и, конечно, **правила**, которые как раз должны способствовать **правильному** отображению замысла пищущего и пониманию этого замысла читающими.

Вот и пошли варианты.

1. ***Хотя брови у него как у Брежнева.***

Да, отсутствие запятой позволяет бегло прочитать предложение с главным ударением на последнем слове. ***Как у БрЕжнева*** не обстоятельство образа действия. Брови не действуют ***по-брежневски***, они вообще не действуют – они сравниваются, находятся в определенном состоянии. Сравнительный оборот выступает в роли сказуемого. На Грамоте.ру, затертое до дыр, можно найти следующее ([**Постановка запятой перед союзом КАК**](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183)).

> **Не обособляются обороты с союзом КАК в пяти случаях:**
> <...>
> 4. Если союз КАК стоит между подлежащим и сказуемым (без этого союза там требовалось бы поставить тире), например: *Озеро как зеркало*...

Без оборота с КАК высказывание не имеет законченного смысла. А обособленные обороты, как правило, можно удалить без нарушения синтаксического строя. Запятая не подходит.

2. ***Хотя брови у него... как у Брежнева.***

При такой пунктуации мы показываем заминку, подбираем слова для сравнения.

3. ***Хотя брови у него – как у Брежнева.***

Такой случай несет экспрессию. Ударение падает и на подлежащее.
Более полную информацию можно прочитать в справочнике Розенталя ([**Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92)).

> **Примечание.** Обычно тире не ставится:
> <...>
> 2) если в роли связки выступают сравнительные союзы ***как, будто, словно, точно, вроде как, всё равно что*** и т. п.: ***Речи как речи*** (Фурм.); ***Звёзды будто*** мелкие ***алмазы***; ***Облака словно*** сказочные ***чудовища***; Сегодня ***небо точно море.***
> Отступления от этого положения у писателей-классиков и у современных авторов связаны с прежними пунктуационными нормами или с желанием подчеркнуть оттенок сравнения, содержащийся в сказуемом: *Твои **речи — будто** острый **нож*** (Л.); *Эта **девушка — как праздник!*** (Аж.)...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119638/discussion-on-answer-by--------).

Answer (score 4):

Это **комментарий на ответ** Александр Стрелец

***Хотя брОви у него, как у БрЕжнева.***

Александр, я только сегодня прочитала ваш ответ, а то бы ситуация заинтересовала меня раньше. Но сейчас разговор не об этом, давайте вспомним, что это сайт русского языка, и **мне хочется именно с вами посоветоваться  и поговорить на эту тему** (просто не с кем больше).

1. Я вот читаю вопрос автора: "тяжко отличать сравнительный оборот от обстоятельства образа действия". **Я с ним полностью согласна**, мне тоже бывает тяжко, это сложная тема.  И к каждому предложению нужен индивидуальный подход, как же их закрывать!

А вот всем остальным (кроме вас, как я думаю) **это легко,** ну просто как нечего делать. Они точно знают, что это **необособленное сказуемое во всех случаях.**

**А знаете, откуда такая уверенность?** Они, как я думаю, достигли **того потолка формальных правил,** о котором нам говорил наш уважаемый новый участник JKlen. А вот когда мы начнем развиваться дальше,  но нам «дадут» правила более высокого уровня. Можно было бы, конечно, подождать, но вот какая неувязочка.  Пока мы закрепились на этом уровне, жизнь не стоит на месте, а практическое правописание  не стоит на месте тоже. А еще вернее то, что **мы просто неправильно оценивали его.**

2. Почему я делаю такой вывод именно из данного вопроса? **Я зашла в Нацкорпус** и набрала для поиска  «у него как у» и получила результат – 209 примеров.

На первых же страницах вижу такие предложения:

(1)  Он самый как есть выжига, пройдоха, и рОжа у него, как у обезьЯны! [И. С. Тургенев. Конец Чертопханова (1872)]

Клаус Кински вещает, как фюрер, а **прОфиль у него, как у дУче**. [А. Ю. Беляков. // «Волга», 2015]

Ну, любит человек нотации почитать, ну, **взглЯд у него, как у осьминОга**,  [Елизавета Козырева. (2001)]

**ЗУбы у него, как у настоящего хИщника**. [Валентин Постников. Приключения Карандаша и Самоделкина на «Дрындолете» (1997)]

(2)  **Голова у него как у львА**, а тело ― как у змеИ. [Виктор Пелевин. Бэтман Аполло (2013)]

Физзарядка **такАя** у него, как у клОуна: крепче стенки голова. [Светлана Василенко (1997-2000)]

Правда, **внЕшность у него ― как у** хорошо загорелого  рУсского. [Григорий Пунанов. «Известия», 2002.04.22]

3. Мы видим разные варианты оформления  **и делаем выводы:**

(1) **Обособление оборота встречается часто**, в приведенных примерах его **нет** в сложном предложении с противопоставлением: Голова у него **как у львА**, а тело ― как у змеИ. Здесь делается перестановка ударений.

(2) При наличии местоимения «такая» оно выполняет функцию сказуемого, поэтому оборот обособляется однозначно: Физзарядка **такАя** у него, как у клОуна: крепче стенки голова.

(3) Иногда вместо запятой ставится **тире**.

А как же быть с необособленным оборотом в роли сказуемого. Обособляется здесь оборот, и это не редкость.

Дело в том, что всем правит **интонация и расстановка логических ударений,** но всё это выше нашего потолка. А мы по-прежнему уверены, что перед нами необособленный оборот-сказумое.

Но можно ли это объяснить **грамматически?**  Да можно, и очень просто – во всех этих предложениях (с обособлением)  сказуемым является **пропущенные  местоимения** «такой, такая, такое», а далее следует обособленный оборот.

**Что вы обо всем этом думаете?** Пожалуйста, ответьте, когда найдете время.

Comment: Отвечу, конечно! Сроки не устанавливаю. Но при прочтении сразу вырисовываются картинки будущего ответа. Я не смотрел в Нацкорпус, но точно был уверен... или, скорее, почувствовал кожей (опять что-то из разряда "сверхвсякоймеры" интуиции), что запятая так или иначе покажет себя во весь свой рост в подобного рода предложениях.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Тогда до новых встреч  и обсуждения новых вопросов.

Comment: Вот 2 классических примера из Розенталя на эту тему: Год, как жизнь (название кинофильма) — ‘год подобен жизни’, а не ‘год есть жизнь’ . Небо как море. 

В чем смысловая разница между "Небо такое, как море" и "Небо как море"? Да ни в чем, особенном. Может степень сравнения выше у 2.

Comment: @Sharon Извините, мне кажется, что в Ваши рассуждения вкралась ошибка: _Запятой нет в сложном предложении с противопоставлением или при наличии местоимения «такой»._ Запятая ведь есть. И ещё вот тут: _...сказуемым является пропущенные местоимения «такой, такая, такое»..._

Comment: Римма, не совсем вас поняла. Сравним: (1) ГоловА у него, как у львА.  (2) Голова у него как у львА, а тело ― как у змеИ. Оборот не обособляется в сложном предожении с союзом А, там меняется расстановка ударений.

Comment: Попробую ещё раз. 1. У Вас имеется единственный пример с местоимением "такая": _Физзарядка такАя у него, как у клОуна: крепче стенки голова._ (Запятая есть.) А Вы пишете: _Запятой нет... при наличии местоимения «такой»._ 2. _...сказуемым является пропущенные местоимения «такой, такая, такое»..._ Присутствует, думаю, рассогласование. (Можно так: сказуемым является пропущенное местоимение («такой», «такая», «такое».))

Comment: Спасибо, исправлено.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно:

***Хотя брови у него как у Брежнева.*** (Запятая не нужна.)

См. у Розенталя:

> **§ 42.**
>
> 4. Сравнительный оборот с союзом *как* не выделяется запятыми:
>
> <…>
>
> 4. если сравнительный оборот входит в сказуемое (образует именную
>    часть составного сказуемого) или по смыслу тесно связан со сказуемым
>    (обычно в этих случаях сказуемое не выражает необходимого смысла без
>    сравнительного оборота):
>
> ***… Душонка у тебя как у зайца.***
>
> http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

Comment: Да запятая-то не нужна, кто б сомневался. Но вопрос, видимо, не в этом. Автор там чего-то про смуту говорит и о трудностях... И не очень понятно, что за смута такая - и в чем оные трудности... А вы ему изволите про связь со сказуемым толковать.

Comment: Это вам очень хотелось хоть куда-то вставить свои пять копеек?

Comment: @ParryGott *Это вам очень хотелось хоть куда-то вставить свои пять копеек* - простите, вы это кому?  Извольте научиться хотя бы указывать, с кем хотите поскандалить.

Comment: Ну а если мне, грешному, так я простите, пятью копейками не разбрасываюсь. Не мой уровень. Я себе ставил задачу привести в адекватный, сколько-нибудь премлемый для SE вид вопросы. Вынужден признать, что вашими стараниями у меня все хуже и хуже это получается...

Comment: _behemothus: Автор там чего-то про смуту говорит и о трудностях... И не очень понятно, что за смута такая - и в чем оные трудности... А вы ему изволите про связь со сказуемым толковать_. ===  "Смуту" у автора вопроса вызвало, как он написал, "правило запятой при сравнении". Видимо, он он просто не до конца дочитал это правило. Я лишь показал, в каком пункте **этого правила** говорится об аналогичных нашему случаях, и привёл пример, **максимально похожий** на разбираемое нами предложение.

Answer (score 3):

Запятая не нужна, так как сочетание «как у Брежнева» —  сказуемое.

Comment: Пытался до неё достучаться... Вот: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474503 Бесполезно, как вы и говорили. Никакие аргументы не помогают...