# "Не понял" и вопрос: как правильно написать?

Tags: орфография, вопрос

Иногда в переписке возникают ситуации, когда кто-то чего-то не понял и пытается это уточнить. Часто это выглядит примерно так:

> Я не понял, почему здесь так?

По моему мнению, в такой форме предложение выглядит странно. Наличие знака вопроса воспринимается как будто автор спрашивает, понял ли он. Но суть именно в том, что автор не понял и хочет уточнить причину. Т.е. вопрос должен относиться именно к последней части "почему здесь так", но не к "Я не понял".

Как грамматически правильно построить такого рода предложение?

Comment: Равносильно следующему: *Я не понял. Почему здесь так?* Просто есть двусмысленность, но второй смысл глупый, поэтому норм.

Comment: У вас все правильно. Попозже приведу ссылку на справочник.

Comment: Вопрос может содержаться и в последней части, а не в головной. Когда я глажу кошку, почему она мяучит? Либо без когда: я глажу кошку, почему она мяучит? Первой частью он хочет подчеркнуть, что он не понял, то есть у него есть понимание, всего кроме именно вот этого момента. Все понятно, но именно эта часть не понятна и не увязывается в общий контекст, нарушает целостность восприятия. Не понял почему *здесь*  "так" или "не так", до этого момента противоречий не возникает, а вот здесь не так, не понятно.

Comment: @oleedd а если я хочу спросить по первой части "понял ли я", как будет? `Я не понял "почему здесь так"?` Или как-то иначе?

Comment: Так же и будет. Второй смысл есть. Но при нормальном раскладе скажут: *Понял ли я, почему здесь так?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правило про такие предложения, где первая часть не является вопросительной, а вторая является вопросительной:

В такой ситуации может быть два варианта:

1. Вторая часть произносится без вопросительной интонации, в таком случае вопросительный знак не ставится, а между предложениями ставится запятая. Вот примеры таких предложений:

> Я спросил его, когда он вернётся.
> Они хотели знать, буду ли я есть.

2. Вторая часть произносится с вопросительной интонацией, в таком случае вопросительный знак ставится, а между предложениями двоеточие.

> Я спросил его: ‟Ты кто вообще такой?” (Когда рассказывается о прошлом, то вопросительное предложение цитируется.)
> Я не понимаю: что ты делаешь? (Люди разговаривают в чате и кто-то это пишет, обозначая вопросительную интонацию.)

Перейдём к вашему предложению. Если вы общаетесь с кем-то в чате, то возможны два варианта:

1. Вторая часть произносится (обозначается) без вопросительной интонации, и вопросительный знак не следует ставить, а между предложениями следует ставить запятую. Вы пишете следующее: ‟Я не понял, почему здесь так”. Вы не задаёте прямой вопрос, но человек догадывается, что ему следует объяснить.
2. Вторая часть произносится (обозначается на письме) с вопросительной интонацией. Ставится вопросительный знак и двоеточие. Вы пишете следующее: ‟Я не понял: почему здесь так?” Это уже прямой вопрос.

[Ссылка на эту тему в справочнике Розенталя.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88#pp88)

Comment: Ссылка не открывается

Comment: Уже открывается.

Answer (score 4):

Материал по теме есть [здесь: пункт 4 (примечание)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88#pp88)

А оформить можно так: *Я не понял: **почему здесь так**? Я не понял — **почему здесь так?***  Это БСП (возможно двоеточие или тире).

Двоеточие в БСП: [Пункт 5](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150). Тире во многих случаях  может заменять двоеточие.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147201/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

Второй ответ (**почему нежелательно использовать СПП**)

**Примеры у Розенталя:** *Я прервал речь Савельича **вопросом**, сколько у меня всего денег* (П.); *Корчагин неоднократно **спрашивал** меня, когда он может выписаться*. В обоих предложениях есть вопросительное слово (***спросил, вопрос***), поэтому очевидно, что вопросительной будет  **ВТОРАЯ ЧАСТЬ**. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88#pp88

В вашем же примере глагол "не понял", поэтому нельзя точно сказать, какая часть вопросительная. Этим объясняется **выбор БСП.**

Этот момент я продумала, перед тем как ответить **первый раз.**

**Речевые ситуации с неясным смыслом**:

На письме при использовании СПП запись одинаковая, а вопросительная часть разная.

(1) Зачем ты мне это объясняешь? ***Я не пОнял, почему здесь так?** Это я как раз понял.*

(2) *Там у тебя все было по-другому. **Я не понял, почему здЕсь так**?*